# Alternatives to Hierarchical RL for centralized control tasks?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, learning-algorithms, hierarchical-rl

Consider a problem where the agent must learn to control a hierarchy of agents acting against another such agent in a competitive environment.  The agents on each team need to learn cooperate in order to compete with the other agents.

A hierarchical RL algorithm would seem to be ideal for such a problem, learning a policy that includes sub-policies for sub-agents.  But are there are other types of algorithms that could be used for this kind of task, perhaps ones that are involved centralized cooperation but aren't considered hierarchical RL?